# How does this work and what is it called?

Tags: objective-c, function, parameters

I have trouble understanding how this works and what this feature is called. Basically a function in Objective-C that sends in multiple values separated by `|`.

```
 [apiInstance sbtSubsribeForEvents:SBT_EVENT_SCANNER_APPEARANCE |
 SBT_EVENT_SCANNER_DISAPPEARANCE | SBT_EVENT_SESSION_ESTABLISHMENT |
 SBT_EVENT_SESSION_TERMINATION | SBT_EVENT_BARCODE];
```

Comment: It's the bitwise `or` operation.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe (`|`) operator in C is the bitwise OR (not to be confused with `||`, the logical OR).  For example, `1 | 2` is 3.

```
  0001 // 1
| 0010 // 2
  ----
  0011 // 3
```

What that line of code is doing is ORing all the values together.  The value of each constant is defined such that it uses a different bit than all the other values (i.e. each value is a power of 2).  This means that they can be combined without losing any values.

Comment: Did you mean to say *boolean OR* or *bitwise OR*?

Comment: Those are the same.  Boolean logic as applied to bit manipulation.  In programming, though, we usually only use _boolean_ to refer to logical values (i.e. true and false).

Comment: `|` is the bitwise or, not the boolean or

Comment: Boolean OR makes it sound like it returns either true or false, bitwise OR sounds like it returns two values OR'ed together.

Comment: I got that copied from a framework. It is a single ( | ) operator.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I edited the answer already, but the logic which makes bitwise OR work is boolean logic.  I agree, though, that being specific is a better answer.